# How to auto-indent a splited line with just one tab in vim?

Tags: c, vim

With cindent enabled, if you insert a newline in a "incomplete" statement, it auto-indent like this (example from [here](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/indent.html)):

```
a = b + 9 *
    █
```

But if you do it inside anything that has parentheses, like a function call or a if statement, it auto-indent with double your `'shiftwidth'`:

```
printf("%s %d\n", "this is a number"
        █
```

I want it to insert just one `'shiftwidth'`, like in the first example.

Also, the `+N` cinoption doesn't help: if I do `:set cinoptions+=+0`, although it stop auto-indenting the first example, it still put double my `'shiftwidth'` in cases with a parentheses.

My `.vimrc`:

```
set ts=4 sw=4   
set softtabstop=4
"set expandtab
color vim-material
set guifont=Consolas:h11:cANSI:qDRAFT
set nu
syntax on
set backspace=indent,eol,start
set ruler
set relativenumber
set hidden
set wildmenu
filetype plugin indent on
"set autoindent
set formatoptions-=cro
set rulerformat=%l,%v
set cinoptions+=:0
```

Answer (score 1):

You improperly selected the SO site. I found the answer from information here https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/5818/what-is-the-difference-between-autoindent-and-smartindent-in-vimrc

> `autoindent` essentially tells vim to apply the indentation of the current line to the next (created by pressing <kbd>enter</kbd> in *insert* mode or with <kbd>O</kbd> or <kbd>o</kbd> in *normal* mode.
>
> `smartindent` reacts to the syntax/style of the code you are editing (especially for C). When having it *on* you also should have `autoindent` *on*.
>
> `:help autoindent` also mentions two alternative settings: `cindent` and `indentexpr`, both of which make vim ignore the value of `smartindent`.

I suppose from there you should use the following options

```
:set autoindent
:set nosmartindent
```

And maybe

```
:set noindentexpr
```